# The port 55283 was occupied" errors comes whenever I use ShareIt

Tags: windows-10, port, runtime-error

Today I installed ShareIt Windows software from ShareIt official site. Software installed correctly without any issue, but when I opened it, I am getting prompt "The port 55283 was occupied". I want to know What is port 55283?. Who is occupied that port & Why I am getting this error. I am using Windows 10 OS. I had attached the screenshot of error that I am getting. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Open an elevated command prompt, and run `netstat -a -b > c:\temp\netstat.txt` and let it finish. Go and open the file `c:\temp\netstat.txt` and look for an entry with port ID 55283. This will tell you what application is using that port. You can then close the program using port 55283, and try your application again.

Comment: Is this solution will solve my problem?

Comment: Just to make it clearer, I've added 'You can then close the program using port 55283, and try your application again.'

Comment: Do I have to run this entire line "netstat -a -b > c:\temp\netstat.txt" once

Comment: I am not able to locate netstat file.

Comment: Getting error "The system cannot find the path specified" error after running netstat -a -b > c:\temp\netstat.txt

Comment: Make sure you have a folder in the root of c:\ called temp

Comment: Ok I will create that folder in c drive.

Comment: The file is created "netstat.txt" in temp folder but in that file the information of port "55283" is not available. @spikey_richie

Comment: If 55283 doesn't appear in that file, then the port is not in use.

Comment: Then why this error is coming when I am opening ShareIt software?

Comment: https://shareit.one/how-to-transfer-files-to-pc-using-shareit/ There's a 'Leave a reply' section at the bottom. Best you can do given there's no support or contact details on their website.

Comment: Any other solution to this.

Comment: Use another piece of software. See if you can configure the port SHAREit is using. Why would you not reach out to the creator of the software? I'm just some dude in England working from home, trying to be helpful. I don't work for SHAREit...

Answer (score 0):

that is because you have two versions of shareit installed. First, uninstall the pc application. Second, there might be an application installed using the Microsoft store. Make your pc free of all the instances of the application. Again install, and make sure you open it with the same shortcut that got created.

Still not working?

1. Check if temp folder exists at this path C:\temp
2. If not then create temp folder in C:\ otherwise move to next step
3. Open command prompt as an administrator. And type
   netstat -a -b > c:\temp\netstat.txt
4. Navigate to temp folder and open file netstat.txt
5. Now check which application is using port 55283